# How to add multiple client IP addresses at time in Azure SQL Server using Azure ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template

Currently I am working on to deploy the Azure SQL Database by adding multiple IP addresses under Firewall rules using Azure ARM templates.

This is the code for adding one IP address under Firewall settings of Azure SQL Server.

```
{
      "name": "AllowAllMicrosoftAzureIps",
      "type": "firewallrules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "startIpAddress": "[parameters('startIpAddress')]",
        "endIpAddress": "[parameters('endIpAddress')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('sqlServerName')]"
      ]
    },
```

But I want to add the multiple IP addresses at a time under Firewall settings of Azure SQL Database using Azure ARM templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I believe it would look something like this. Use the `copy` iterator and supply an array of start and end IP addresses.

```json
"parameters": { 
    "firewallIpAddresses": { 
        "type": "object", 
        "defaultValue": [ 
            { "start": "1.1.1.0", "end": "1.1.1.10","clientName": "Client1" },
            { "start": "1.2.3.4", "end": "1.2.3.16","clientName": "Client2" },
            { "start": "1.2.0.1", "end": "1.2.0.20","clientName": "Client3" }
        ] 
    }
},
"resources": [
{
     "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '/', parameters('firewallIpAddresses')[copyIndex()].clientName)]",
     "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallrules",
     "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "properties": {
        "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallIpAddresses')[copyIndex('firewallrulecopy')].start]",
        "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallIpAddresses')[copyIndex('firewallrulecopy')].end]"
     },
     "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('sqlServerName')]"
    ],
    "copy": {
        "name": "firewallrulecopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('firewallIpAddresses'))]"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Dan Wilson, When I added the above code in my azuredeploy.json file and tested the template using deployment script through the PowerShell script at that time I am getting the error like Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat('AllowMicrosoftAzureIps', copyIndex())]' at line '237' column '18' is not valid. Copying nested resources is not supported.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add the index name in the `copyIndex()` function. Does it work after making your edits?

Comment: Yes Dan Wilson, it working fine after I made small changes of your code.

Comment: Just to add, I had issues with the parameter as an "object", switching to "array" allowed it to recognise the parameter being passed in.
Also, if you get "Copying nested resources is not supported", it's likely that you've nested the "firewallRules" under the Microsoft.Sql/servers as a sub resource, you will need to move it to a top level resource to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
  "name": "nba-instance-one",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "sql-server-instance"
    },
    "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "admin",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "password"
    },
    "resources": [ 
        {
            "type": "firewallRules",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "name": "LaptopIp",
            "properties": {
                "startIpAddress": "39.188.172.29",
                "endIpAddress": "39.188.172.29"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', 'sql-server-instance')]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "firewallRules",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "name": "OtherIP",
            "properties": {
                "startIpAddress": "38.171.192.48",
                "endIpAddress": "38.171.192.48"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', 'sql-server-instance')]"
            ]
        }
```

If it's only a few IP addresses you could add more fire wall rules for each IP address.